# How to find constraints between view and the top layout guide?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I do not want to make IBOutlet of the constraint between  view and the top layout guide.I do not want to put identifier also.  I want to find it programatically.Anyone please help me.

Comment: yes i managed to resolve it by iterating over all the constraints of the view and checking if it satisfies the conditions, (constraint.firstItem as? NSObject == self.view && constraint.firstAttribute == .Top) || (constraint.secondItem as? NSObject == self.view && constraint.secondAttribute == .Top)

Answer (score 1):

Select the `constraint` and add the `identifier` 'TopLayOut' like added in the pic below:

[image]

and in your code iterate through the constraints and find the right one as below:

```
 for constraint in self.view.constraints{

            if constraint == "TopLayOut"{
                print("matches")
                break;
            }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I need to find it without putting identifier also.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you have to declare the constraint programatically. Please find the code snippet.

```
let view = UIView()    
let leadingConstraint = view.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor)
let trailingConstraint = view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor)
let topConstraint = view.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor)
let bottomConstraint = view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
var setConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
setConstraints.appendContentsOf([leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])    
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(setConstraints)
```

Please tick If it's helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to find the constraints which i added from Interface Builder.